# asp.net - displaying a dictionary with a list as the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm seeking advice as to what would be the best way to do this in ASP.Net (C#).

I'm trying to create a page that lists a all the staff in our office, and had a summary of 4 weeks worth of their timesheets.

I have a timesheet object for each week which can do all of that, and I figure I can return a Dictionary> to get the data there. But what is the best way of databinding that?

What i want it to display is like this:

```
StaffMember - WEEK 1 (DATE) - WEEK 2 (DATE) - WEEK 3 (DATE) - WEEK 4 (DATE)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOB BUILDER - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[]
OLD MATE    - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[] - Val1, Val2,[]
```

etc etc for all staff. the [] denotes a checkbox which the person who uses this page will check off when they have processed something on their end relating to that weeks timesheet.

My thought is this:
- Have a listview with the item template setup to have table rows and cells, and literals for the values
- onitemdatabound get the keyvaluepair and then set the staff member literal to the name of staff member (which is the key), then set each value from each of the week to be the values from the corresponding timesheet in the list

Problem is that I'm not sure how to dynamically set the date of each week, I guess I could do a findcontrol on the template of the listview or something? Or set the table up outside of the listview? Just all feels a little messy though so I thought I'd get some advice from the clever people at stackoverflow. Is there an easier way to do this?? Is using complicated dictionaries like that frowned upon in .net and is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a quick look through implementing an [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227436.aspx).  Since you'll only be selecting from your data at first, this might be relatively easy to implement.

You could build a class that had a Date property with which you could use to filter the Select() calls to your dictionary.  Then you could manipulate your ObjectDataSource in the code to just give it a new date value whenever you needed to, and then call Databind() on your grid again.